# string.startsWith() Wildcard OR Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

Refactoring some code that uses string.startsWith() in JavaScript. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) don't say you can use wildcard or Regular Expression. What is alternative?

Comment: "What is alternative" ← Use a regular expression and pass in the string itself, do not use `startsWith`

Comment: Use an anchored regular expression, with one of the regular expression methods instead of `startsWith`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.prototype.match` and `regex.prototype.test`.

#### 'string'.match(/regex/):

```js
let a = 'hello'.match(/^[gh]/); // truthy (['h'])
let b = 'gello'.match(/^[gh]/); // truthy (['g'])
let c = 'ello'.match(/^[gh]/); // falsey (null)
console.log(a, b, c);
```

#### /regex/.test('string'):

```js
let a = /^[gh]/.test('hello'); // true
let b = /^[gh]/.test('gello'); // true
let c = /^[gh]/.test('ello'); // false
console.log(a, b, c);
```

The regex symbol `^` ensures the regex matches only at the string start.

Comment: Thank you! Tried to accept answer but says I have to wait 6 minutes. Will do soon!